# Applying function by pairing by names of a list and file name

Tags: r, list, file

I have a `list` object and a number of ".csv" files that I would like to load in, in order to run the `mean` function in a very specific manner.

My list `l1` contains 5 elements each with a number in it, and my .csv files each when loaded in provided a single number. I would like to pair the .csv files with the elements in the list based on the names(i.e., A,B,C,D,E).

My expected outcome would look something like the `expected` object created below. Is there a good way of doing this?

```
l1 <- list(2,3,4,5,6)
names(l1) <- c("A", "B", "C", "D", "E")

# Dummy .csv when loaded in 
A1_csv <- 4
B2_csv <- 6
C3_csv <- 7
D4_csv <- 8
E5_csv <- 9

expected <- list(mean(c(A1_csv, l1[[1]])),
                 mean(c(B2_csv, l1[[2]])),
                 mean(c(C3_csv, l1[[3]])),
                 mean(c(D4_csv, l1[[4]])),
                 mean(c(E5_csv, l1[[5]]))
                 )
```

Comment: Why do you only reference `l1[[1]]`? I would expect `l1[[2]]`, etc.

Comment: This is almost set up perfectly to use `Map`, but while you have `l1` as a `list`, you have the CSV variables broken out into individual objects. Would it make more sense to have a `list` (perhaps named `CSVs`) for that part as well? That way you could use `Map(mean, CSVs, l1)`

Comment: Sorry, that was a typo. The `l1[[1]]` were suppose to change. I've edited the post to the show that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For the example data the solution is very straight forward and mentioned already:

```r
a <- as.list(setNames(2:6, letters[1:5]))
b <- c(4, 6:9)
Map(mean, a, b)
#> $a
#> [1] 2
#> 
#> $b
#> [1] 3
#> 
#> $c
#> [1] 4
#> 
#> $d
#> [1] 5
#> 
#> $e
#> [1] 6
```

<sup>Created on 2022-03-07 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v2.0.1)</sup>

However, if these list may change a bit and may not contain the same `names`, then you need something a little more flexible to find the common names and subset the lists first:

```r
a <- as.list(setNames(1:10, letters[1:10]))
b <- as.list(setNames(20:5, letters[20:5]))

set <- intersect(names(a), names(b))

Map(
  function(i, j) {
    mean(i, j)
  },
  i = a[set],
  j = b[set]
)
#> $e
#> [1] 5
#> 
#> $f
#> [1] 6
#> 
#> $g
#> [1] 7
#> 
#> $h
#> [1] 8
#> 
#> $i
#> [1] 9
#> 
#> $j
#> [1] 10
```

<sup>Created on 2022-03-07 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v2.0.1)</sup>